# reading from a file in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++

i am making a project in clr windows form using c++ and im having problem in retrieving the data from the file in a template(vector) when the form is loaded. my form has the button to save the code which calls the save method in the class coded as below. pls suggest what should be the code to retrieve the file, thank you.here record isthe name of the vector.

```
int men_database::save(int count)
{ ofstream out;
out.open("MALE.txt",ios::out|ios::binary);
if(!out)
    return -1;
  else
      {for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
   {out<<'\n'<<record[i].getid();
    out<<'\n'<<record[i].getname();
    out<<'\n'<<record[i].getsize();
    out<<'\n'<<record[i].getcolor();
    out<<'\n'<<record[i].getprice();
    out<<'\n'<<record[i].getpic();
    out<<'\n'<<record[i].getwatch();
    }
    out.close();
}//else ends
return 1;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some basic code for reading/writing. Though you might find something better elsewhere. `\n` is used as delimiter. Each record should have 2 fields (in yours it is 7 fields). Each field must be single-line string. Ps, you get more attention with c++ tag on your question.

```
int main()
{
    {
        ofstream f("data.txt");

        f << "id1"   << endl;
        f << "name1" << endl;
        f << endl;

        f << "id2"   << endl; 
        f << "name2" << endl;
        f << endl; 
    }

    {
        ifstream f("data.txt");
        string id;
        string name;
        while (f)
        {
            f >> id; 
            f >> name;
            if (!f) break;
            cout << "id:   " << id   << endl;
            cout << "name: " << name << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```